# Collar neighborhood theorem- Cobordism

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

I am studying cobordism theory and I basically follow Milnor's book, Characteristic classes.

I want to prove that cobordism is a transitive relation so I need the collar neighborhood theorem. In Milnor's book (theorem 17.1) the proof is omitted because is similar to the proof of the transversality theorem (theorem 11.1). Although I proved transversality theorem, I don't understand why the collar neighborhood theorem follows from it. I checked the same proof in Lee's book "introduction to smooth manifolds",  but he uses flows on manifolds and I don't know anything about that. 
 Any hints?

In general,  any recommendations about an introductory book on Cobordism theory?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to know the tubular neighborhood theorem first. Then you need to know that the boundary has trivial normal bundle. That's the proof.

Comment: Thank you. You mean that  the normal bundle of the boundary of X is trivial in X, right? Do you have any reference for that?

Answer (score 4):

Any manifold book worth its salt should prove this.

Put a Riemannian metric on $X$; then for every point in the boundary, there is a unique tangent vector in $T_p X$ that is orthogonal to the boundary, of norm 1, and points inwards. This provides a trivialization of the normal bundle of $\partial X$ in $X$. Now, how would one prove the tubular neighborhood theorem here? (Note that we can't invoke the standard one without modifications, since we have a neighborhood of "half" the normal bundle.) Flow along this vector field... (I think Lee's proof is the "standard" one.) A proof that completely avoids flows should work if you live as subsets of $\Bbb R^n$. See Bredon for a proof along these lines, IIRC. I don't think Bredon does much with flows in his book.